@capacitor-firebase/firestore plugin - getCountFromServer equivalent?
I'm using this plugin for my ReactJS + Capacitor project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-firebase/firestore#getcollection
However, I don't see any equivalent of getCountFromServer in their documentation. Does any of you have an idea if there's any workaround to achieve the same result? I would like to get the number of documents that fulfill certain criteria, but without incurring the cost of reading them all.
I'm a total beginner with that, so I'll really appreciate your patience and help ;) Thank you!

I'm the maintainer of the Capacitor Firebase plugins. This method is not yet supported. Feel free to create a feature request on GitHub and we will implement that.

Could you also let me know what is the correct way to use ArrayUnion with your plugin? I want to add a new entry to an existing array in Firebase, but I can't find the correct syntax on how to do it. Thank you.

Please create a separate discussion on GitHub/StackOverflow for this.
